# Automatically rename uploaded files not to conflict with existing files using SFTP (WinSCP)

Tags: windows, command-line, sftp, winscp

I have file named with **A.txt**, Using batch command to copy the file to SFTP Server. After copying the **A.txt**, to copy the **A.txt** again to SFTP on same path.There is no possible same name with two files on same path, I want to rename the second copied file like **A2.txt**.

How to use the '***New name***' command in WinSCP command line?

I copying the multiple files with file extension (*.txt), only I want to rename the file which already exist with same name in SFTP Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*"New name"* command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_overwrite) in WinSCP GUI cannot automatically rename uploaded file not to conflict with existing files.

Neither there's such a function in [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

---

Though you can code this using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), for example using [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell):

```powershell
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    $sessionOptions.HostName = "example.com"
    $sessionOptions.UserName = "username"
    $sessionOptions.Password = "password"
    $sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="

    $localPath = "c:\local\path\*.txt"
    $remotePath = "/remote/path/"

    try
    {
        # Connect
        Write-Host "Connecting..."
        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
        $session.SessionLogPath = "session.log"
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Upload files
        Write-Host "Uploading..."

        $localFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath

        foreach ($localFile in $localFiles)
        {
            $name = $localFile.Name;
            Write-Host "Found file $name"

            $index = 0;
            while ($session.FileExists($remotePath + $name))
            {
                Write-Host "$name exists already in remote directory"
                $index++;
                $name = $localFile.Name + " ($index)"
            }

            Write-Host "Uploading as $name ..."
            $session.PutFiles($localFile, $remotePath + $name).Check()
        }

        Write-Host "Done"
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: please my review question again, i want to rename the file while transferring to SFTP server

Comment: That's what I answered. Read my answer again. The first `put` uploads the local file `file.txt` to a remote file `file_one.txt`. While the second `put` uploads it as `file_two.txt`.

Comment: I transferring the multiple files, during the time i using file extension like '*.txt', And i don't want to rename all files, I want to rename only which are files as same name already exist in the SFTP server

Comment: Your question down not mention multiple files not any extension. You need to elaborate on how you want to rename the files automatically, if you are uploading multiple files. That's something the *"New name"* command in WinSCP GUI cannot do.

Comment: @VigneshRajendran See my edited answer for a solution using PowerShell.

Comment: @VigneshRajendran A simple solution would be to appened a date-time stamp to all your files before uploading them to some SFTP directory. You can do that with a batch FOR loop using substitutions keeping the original names and then appened the `<origfilename>_<YYYYMMDD_hhmmss>.txt`... WinSCP is awesome!! Keep up the great work @MartinPrikryl... many props to you!!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl WinSCP is awesome!! Keep up the great work... many props to you!!